# How do I get the value a User has selected from a Data Validation List?

Tags: excel, vba, list, validation

I have a Data Validation List in Cell D10. When the user selects a value, I would like to copy the value to a different cell on the same worksheet.

When I try

```
Range("G10").value= Range("D10").value
```

nothing is returned.

As D10 is a Data Validation List, I also tried

```
Range("G10").value=Range("D10").validation.value
```

(from an example code found online) but still nothing is returned.

Comment: `Range("G10").value= Range("D10").value` is the right way to go. What is your validation like? Can you share more detail?

Comment: Just in case, try .value2 instead of value.
However, there may something wrong with other things you don't show us.

Comment: How is your code being triggered?  Is the sheet with the validation list active when the code runs?

Comment: What is the `ActiveSheet` when the code runs?  Have you tried [Fully Qualifying your Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22080453/9290986)?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$D$10" Then
        Range("G10").Value = Range("D10").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

It must be placed in the code of the sheet containing your cell with data validation. I guess you didn't used the $ to identify the cell.

Comment: By the way if i did something wrong answering, please tell me. I am fairly new. ^^ Anyway: Target.Address does use $. If you omit them, it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, he said "when a user select a value". Can there be any other way to catch the event?

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey `Target.Address` only uses "$" because [those are the Default Arguments for `Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) - you could use `Target.Address(False,False)` to get "D10" instead